# Process in ubuntu keeps starting even though it is not installed

Tags: linux, process

On a `Jetson TX1` with the stock Ubuntu 16.04 installed, `rsync` keeps starting on its own and taking 100% of one CPU even though it is not installed.

[image]
[image]

Is there a way to stop that process and why it is doing that even though it is not installed ?

Comment: If it's really rsync, are you sure it only comes from the rsync package?

Answer (score 1):

The `Command` shown can be spoofed by the running process. ([Example with Perl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174698))

A more reliable way to find the binary of the process is by running this command, where `1506` is the PID that you found from your `htop` output:

```
sudo file /proc/1506/exe
```

Sample output:

```
deltik@node51 [~]$ sudo file /proc/1506/exe
/proc/1506/exe: symbolic link to /usr/bin/plasmashell
```

In the sample output above, the actual binary of PID 1506 was `/usr/bin/plasmashell`.

Note that you'll only be able to do this for the suspect process that is currently running, not for processes that have already exited or been killed.

You can also find out what kind of files the process is doing with this command (again replacing `1506` with the current PID):

```
sudo lsof -p 1506
```

And you can watch the system calls and signals of the process and its subprocesses in realtime like so:

```
sudo strace -vfts1000 -p 1506
```

`file`, `lsof`, and `strace` should be enough to paint a good picture of what the process really is and help you narrow down why it's running.